# How (or what is the best way) to raise and / or separate an LED from the PCB?

Tags: led, socket, space

I'm designing a PCB where I have to locate two super flux LEDs like [this one](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/50/R50RG2-F-0160-880891.pdf).

[image: photo of LED from Bivar datasheet]

---

[image: mechanical dimensions from Bivar datasheet]

---

The problem is that it has to be elevated, approximately, 8 mm from the PCB. What is the best way to do this? What type of socket, spacers, standoff... is usually used in this case?

Comment: Why do you need to elevate them 8mm?  The pins already have standoffs built in to them that presumably put them at the manufacturers recommended height from the PCB.

Comment: Considering the pin length + device height sum to 7.4mm I'd say you're out of luck unless you're willing to consider either: a sub-board, or a different LED. With regular LEDs I'd have suggested cutting an 8mm length of heatshrink tubing and slipping it over a pin.

Comment: Could you use pin sockets to elevate the part?

Comment: The 0298xxxx part within this product line is an example of what I was referring to in previous comment.  https://www.mill-max.com/assets/pdfs/metric/174M.pdf

Comment: SIL socket strip might be easy. You don't have to connect anything to the middle position, but it might be a good idea to solder it anyway so it can't rattle.

Comment: Use a light pipe. Do not elevate. You are welcome.

Comment: Although I think this is likely an XY problem, there is a category in mouser called "washable standoffs" or something like that. Could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Solder the LED to a  0.062" PCB
0.062" + 0.25" ≈ 8 mm
Use a 3 pin 0.25" high header on the bottom side.

[image]

---

If there will be significant vibration add two 0.25" hex standoffs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I would either look for a light pipe, or just make a small through-hole pcb with footprints for the led, and for some long 0.1 pitch headers that would go down to the main PCB.

You can get a few hundred small custom PCBs for next to nothing these days.

The only downside I can see for this solution is that it will probably require a jig during soldering to get the right stand-off height.

Comment: There are headers intended for this, they have two sections of the black plastic. PCB Stacker headers in customizable heights like Samtec's EW-12-12-G-S-400 or TW-02-04-F-S-320-SM. No need for a jig to ensure right height.